# Есть ли ошибка в согласовании?

Tags: времена

Есть ли ошибка в согласовании времён в данном предложении: "Пока звучит музыка, он откроет вам свои тайны"?
Заранее благодарю

Comment: Уточните, кто "он"?

Comment: По тексту - художник

Comment: Ну да, все согласовано, проблем нет.